# IntegrityError with a foreignKey

Tags: django

i have these models, states and cities,

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and im getting a "IntegrityError (1048, "Column 'state_id' cannot be null")" when i save the form, the weird thing is that the state are created, this is what im doing

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
    city = form.cleaned_data['city_name']
    state = form.cleaned_data['state_name']

    m = State.objects.get_or_create(name=state)
    state_id = m[0].id
    City.objects.get_or_create(name=state, id=state_id)
    form.save()
```

what can i do?

```
    class StoreForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'


class StoreGoogleMapForm(StoreForm):
    city_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}
        )
    )
    state_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}
        )
    )

    class Meta(StoreForm.Meta):
        exclude = (
            'state', 'city'
        )
        widgets = {
            'retailer': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'lon': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'lat': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(StoreGoogleMapForm, self).clean()
        city_name = cleaned_data.get("city_name")
        state_name = cleaned_data.get("state_name")

        return cleaned_data


class NewStore(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Store
template_name = "new_store.html"
form_class = StoreGoogleMapForm

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(NewStore, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    ctx['cobrand'] = self.retailer

    return ctx

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.retailer = get_object_or_404(Cobrand, pk=kwargs['pk'])

    self.object = Store(retailer=self.retailer)

    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)

    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

def form_valid(self, form):
    city = form.cleaned_data['city_name']
    state = form.cleaned_data['state_name']

    m = State.objects.get_or_create(name=state)
    City.objects.get_or_create(name=city, state=m[0])
    form.save()
    messages.add_message(
        self.request,
        messages.SUCCESS,
        'The store was successfuly created!',
        extra_tags='success'
    )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('store_list', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.retailer = get_object_or_404(Cobrand, pk=kwargs['pk'])

    self.object = Store(retailer=self.retailer)

    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)

    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: @sax sorry didnt notice that

Comment: change as City.objects.get_or_create(name=city, state=m[0])

Comment: ok there is something strange here. as `State.shortname` is mandatory (no `null=True`) how `State.objects.get_or_create(name=state)` can work ? Please share the `Store` model

Answer (score 0):

fix the line as

```
City.objects.get_or_create(name=city, state=m[0])
```

you don't need `form.save()`.

Anyway this code is a bit strange, what about your Form?

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'California'

Comment: with the state=m[0] ->(1048, "Column 'state_id' cannot be null"), im posting the form right now

Answer (score 0):

get_or_create returns two parameters https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create and you can then pass the object straight into the next statement.

```
state, created = State.objects.get_or_create(name=state)
City.objects.get_or_create(name=state, state=state)
```

suspect you shouldn't be doing this in form_valid but without rest of your code, can't be sure.

Comment: i paste the entire view